# No such file or directory' while attempting to get adb version

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, adt

I had install Android adt bundle for linux in my computer(Ubuntu 13.04). But now when I run my eclipse in adt bundle following error appers:-

```
2014-11-04 13:25:50 - adb] Unexpected exception 'Cannot run program "/home/bharath/andriod/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory' while attempting to get adb version from '/home/bharath/andriod/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/adb'
```

I had also tried to run the following commands in my terminal:-

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

also

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386
```

I had also tried the commands given in the following links:-

> 1. [Eclipse ADT Unexpected exception 'Cannot run program'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777316/eclipse-adt-unexpected-exception-cannot-run-program)
> 2. [Error message when setting up ADT in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996167/error-message-when-setting-up-adt-in-linux)
> 3. [Android SDK on a 64-bit linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710499/android-sdk-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine/10473415#10473415)
> 4. [Ubuntu 64 with Android 64 Bundle cannot find adb executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972641/ubuntu-64-with-android-64-bundle-cannot-find-adb-executable)

But the issue is not resolved, Inspite I get the following output on executing those commands on my terminal.

```
bharath@bharath-PC:/home$ sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
[sudo] password for bharath: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-exe-thumbnailer : Depends: icoutils
                         Depends: imagemagick
 lib32ncurses5 : Depends: lib32tinfo5 (= 5.9-10ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
 libcapi20-3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libexif12:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libgif4:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
                                        Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not going to be installed
                                        Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 (>= 0.10.36) but it is not going to be installed
                                        Depends: liborc-0.4-0:i386 (>= 1:0.4.16) but it is not going to be installed
                                        Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libhtml-form-perl : Depends: libhtml-parser-perl but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libhttp-message-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libhtml-tree-perl : Depends: libhtml-parser-perl but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libwww-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libhttp-cookies-perl : Depends: libhttp-message-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libhttp-daemon-perl : Depends: libhttp-message-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libhttp-negotiate-perl : Depends: libhttp-message-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libice6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 libio-socket-ssl-perl : Depends: libnet-ssleay-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libjbig0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libjpeg8:i386 : Depends: libjpeg-turbo8:i386 (>= 1.1.90+svn722-1ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed
 liblzma5:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libopenal1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.23) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 1:0.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libpcre3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libsm6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libuuid1:i386 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libvorbis0a:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libogg0:i386 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libvorbisenc2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not going to be installed
 libwrap0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 libxdmcp6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libxpm4:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
bharath@bharath-PC:/home$
```

and on running the apt-get -f install I get the following output:-

```
bharath@bharath-PC:/home$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ant ant-optional antlr3 aspectj bsh bsh-gcj default-jdk-doc gcj-4.7-base gcj-4.7-jre-lib javahelp2 jetty jsvc junit junit-doc junit4
  junit4-doc libantlr-java libapache-pom-java libasm3-java libaspectj-java libbeansbinding-java libbetter-appframework-java libbindex-java
  libbytelist-java libcglib-java libcommons-beanutils-java libcommons-codec-java libcommons-collections3-java libcommons-compress-java
  libcommons-daemon-java libcommons-digester-java libcommons-logging-java libcommons-net1-java libcommons-parent-java libdb-java libdb-je-java
  libdb5.1-java libdb5.1-java-jni libeasymock-java libfelix-framework-java libfelix-main-java libflute-java libfreemarker-java libgcj-bc
  libgcj-common libgcj13 libgeronimo-jpa-2.0-spec-java libgeronimo-osgi-support-java libhamcrest-java libhamcrest-java-doc libice-dev
  libicu4j-java libini4j-java libjcodings-java libjemmy2-java libjetty-java libjline-java libjna-java libjoda-convert-java libjoda-time-java
  libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libjsch-java libjtidy-java libjvyamlb-java libjzlib-java liblucene2-java libmysql-java
  libnb-absolutelayout-java libnb-apisupport3-java libnb-ide14-java libnb-java5-java libnb-javaparser-java libnb-org-openide-modules-java
  libnb-org-openide-util-java libnb-org-openide-util-lookup-java libnb-platform-devel-java libnb-platform13-java libnetx-java libogg0:i386
  liboro-java libosgi-compendium-java libosgi-core-java libosgi-foundation-ee-java libpostgresql-jdbc-java libpthread-stubs0
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libregexp-java libsac-java libsac-java-gcj libsequence-library-java libserf1 libservlet2.5-java
  libsimple-validation-java libslf4j-java libsm-dev libsqljet-java libstdc++6:i386 libstringtemplate-java libsvn-java libsvn1
  libsvnclientadapter-java libsvnkit-java libswing-layout-java libswingx1-java libtrilead-ssh2-java libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libvorbis0a:i386
  libvorbisenc2:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev
  libxdmcp6:i386 libxerces2-java libxml-commons-external-java libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java libxpm4:i386 libxt-dev libxz-java openjdk-6-jdk
  openjdk-7-doc x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gcc-4.7-base:i386 icoutils imagemagick imagemagick-common libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6:i386 libc6-dev libffi6:i386 libfftw3-double3 libgcc1:i386
  libglib2.0-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libhtml-parser-perl libhttp-message-perl libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg-turbo8:i386
  liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5 libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libogg0:i386
  liborc-0.4-0:i386 libselinux1:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libuuid1:i386 libwww-perl libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxml2 libxml2:i386
  zlib1g:i386
Suggested packages:
  libterm-readline-gnu-perl libterm-readline-perl-perl imagemagick-doc autotrace enscript ffmpeg gimp gnuplot grads hp2xx html2ps libwmf-bin
  mplayer povray radiance texlive-base-bin transfig ufraw-batch glibc-doc glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386 libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev
  gstreamer0.10-tools:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386 libdata-dump-perl libcrypt-ssleay-perl libauthen-ntlm-perl
Recommended packages:
  xml-core:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-4.7-base:i386 icoutils imagemagick imagemagick-common libc6:i386 libffi6:i386 libfftw3-double3 libgcc1:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386
  libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libhtml-parser-perl libhttp-message-perl libjpeg-turbo8:i386 liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmagickcore5
  libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5 libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libogg0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libselinux1:i386 libstdc++6:i386
  libuuid1:i386 libwww-perl libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxml2:i386 zlib1g:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libjpeg-turbo8 libxml2
5 upgraded, 30 newly installed, 0 to remove and 305 not upgraded.
48 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 21.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 35.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libc6-dev libc-dev-bin libc6 gcc-4.7-base libgcc1 libc6 libffi6 libselinux1 zlib1g libglib2.0-0 libxml2 libxml2 libgstreamer0.10-0
  liborc-0.4-0 libuuid1 libogg0 libxau6 libxcb1 libx11-6 libstdc++6 libhtml-parser-perl libhttp-message-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libjpeg-turbo8
  libjpeg-turbo8 libnet-http-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libwww-perl icoutils libfftw3-double3 imagemagick-common libmagickcore5
  libmagickwand5 imagemagick libmagickcore5-extra
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main libc6-dev amd64 2.17-0ubuntu5.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main libc6-dev amd64 2.17-0ubuntu5.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main libc-dev-bin amd64 2.17-0ubuntu5.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main gcc-4.7-base i386 4.7.3-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main libc6 amd64 2.17-0ubuntu5.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libgcc1 i386 1:4.7.3-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main libc6 i386 2.17-0ubuntu5.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main libc6 i386 2.17-0ubuntu5.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libffi6 i386 3.0.13-2ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libselinux1 i386 2.1.9-5ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main zlib1g i386 1:1.2.7.dfsg-13ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libglib2.0-0 i386 2.36.0-1ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main libxml2 amd64 2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main libxml2 amd64 2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main libxml2 i386 2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main libxml2 i386 2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libgstreamer0.10-0 i386 0.10.36-1ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main liborc-0.4-0 i386 1:0.4.17-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libuuid1 i386 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu8
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libogg0 i386 1.3.0-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libxau6 i386 1:1.0.7-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main libxcb1 i386 1.8.1-2ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main libxcb1 i386 1.8.1-2ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main libx11-6 i386 2:1.5.0-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main libx11-6 i386 2:1.5.0-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libstdc++6 i386 4.7.3-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libhtml-parser-perl amd64 3.69-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libhttp-message-perl all 6.03-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libnet-ssleay-perl amd64 1.48-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main libjpeg-turbo8 amd64 1.2.1-0ubuntu2.13.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main libjpeg-turbo8 amd64 1.2.1-0ubuntu2.13.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main libjpeg-turbo8 i386 1.2.1-0ubuntu2.13.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main libjpeg-turbo8 i386 1.2.1-0ubuntu2.13.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libnet-http-perl all 6.03-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main liblwp-protocol-https-perl all 6.03-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libwww-perl all 6.04-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe icoutils amd64 0.30.0-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libfftw3-double3 amd64 3.3.3-2ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main imagemagick-common all 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main imagemagick-common all 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main libmagickcore5 amd64 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main libmagickcore5 amd64 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main libmagickwand5 amd64 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main libmagickwand5 amd64 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main imagemagick amd64 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main imagemagick amd64 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main libmagickcore5-extra amd64 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main libmagickcore5-extra amd64 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6-dev_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc-dev-bin_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.7/gcc-4.7-base_4.7.3-1ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.7/libgcc1_4.7.3-1ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi6_3.0.13-2ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libselinux/libselinux1_2.1.9-5ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zlib/zlib1g_1.2.7.dfsg-13ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib2.0/libglib2.0-0_2.36.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2_2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2_2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4.3_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gstreamer0.10/libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/orc/liborc-0.4-0_0.4.17-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/libuuid1_2.20.1-5.1ubuntu8_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libo/libogg/libogg0_1.3.0-4_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxau/libxau6_1.0.7-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcb/libxcb1_1.8.1-2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-6_1.5.0-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.7/libstdc++6_4.7.3-1ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libh/libhtml-parser-perl/libhtml-parser-perl_3.69-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libh/libhttp-message-perl/libhttp-message-perl_6.03-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnet-ssleay-perl/libnet-ssleay-perl_1.48-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo8_1.2.1-0ubuntu2.13.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo8_1.2.1-0ubuntu2.13.04.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnet-http-perl/libnet-http-perl_6.03-2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libl/liblwp-protocol-https-perl/liblwp-protocol-https-perl_6.03-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libw/libwww-perl/libwww-perl_6.04-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/icoutils/icoutils_0.30.0-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fftw3/libfftw3-double3_3.3.3-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/imagemagick-common_6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickcore5_6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickwand5_6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/imagemagick_6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickcore5-extra_6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
bharath@bharath-PC:/home$
```

But the error still remains the same. Any Help will save me my World and will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you do a apt-get update before upgrade or install?

Comment: @PatrickB. on running the "apt-get update" command on terminal it gives O/P as: 
"E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead." So I think some packages are not installed.

Comment: Then you have a problem with your /etc/apt/sources.list* . Maybe your Ubuntu version is too old and not anymore supported by Ubuntu

Comment: @PatrickB. So if I upgrade my Ubuntu then will it fix my issue.?

Comment: It might fix your issue, but is likely to create tons of others if you are using your Ubuntu installation for something else than to use ADT.

Comment: @PatrickB. Then whats the best thing to do for me to solve the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64222/discussion-between-pravinsingh-waghela-and-patrick-b).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux you need to install IA32 library Because  Linux 64-bit ADT bundle comes with a 32 Bit adb under adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb ... This is also a problem under other distributions, e.g. Fedora 17

Try this: `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 zlib1g:i386`

You could also achieve the same by installing the following 32 bit packages:-

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386
```

also to run an emulator you need the following lib file.

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386
```

Comment: Almost there... you'll also need zlib1g:i386 and then you really done

Comment: @dant3 thanks I had edited my answer you can check that. Thanks for the suggestion,